# String parse and make new array of search

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, reactjs, parsing

I get from backend a string like this (im using `<pre></pre>` to format this the way as it is in backend database):

```
Main responsibilities will include:
 - Driving creation of customer attractive brand
 - Making a significant impact on lead generation and quality of the incoming pipeline
 - Creating marketing materials (Company overview, Company presentation, Case studies, Brochure, Video)
 - Online Advertisement
```

I am trying to parse this string and get all  -*something* (strings that starts from '-') into one array of those items. So I need to get

`let arr = ["Driving creation of customer attractive brand", "Making a significant impact on lead generation and quality of the incoming pipeline", "...", "Online Advertisement"]`

How can achieve this, any thoughts?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this example:

```js
const str = `Main responsibilities will include:
 - Driving creation of customer attractive brand
 - Making a significant impact on lead generation and quality of the incoming pipeline
 - Creating marketing materials (Company overview, Company presentation, Case studies, Brochure, Video)
 - Online Advertisement`;

let regex = /(?<=^\s-\s).*/gm;
let match = str.match(regex);
console.log(match);
```

Details at regex101: https://regex101.com/r/xdyCzO/1
Some notes:
– `(?<=^\s-\s)` = positive lookbehind, it get all things after `-` begin of each sentences (\s = 1 space, ^ = begin of line)
– `.*` = anything except newline, * mean zero or more